# SVG 'g' element throwing error in IE8 (using r2d3, d3.chart)

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-8, d3.js

I'm attempting to use [r2d3](https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3) in IE8 to draw a multi-series linegraph.

On page load in IE8, I get the following error:

`TypeError: Unable to get property 'attr' of undefined or null reference undefined`

which is triggered by the following d3 code:

```
chart.areas.grid = chart.base.append('g')
  .classed('grid', true)
  .attr('width', chart.margins.left - chart.margins.right)
  .attr('height', chart.h - chart.margins.bottom - chart.margins.top)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + chart.margins.left + ',0)');
```

If I replace the 'g' element with something else, the code continues onto the next 'g' element and throws the same error.

I can't figure out what's causing this, considering others have successfully used 'g' elements in IE8 with r2d3.

I'm also using the relatively new framework [d3.chart](https://github.com/misoproject/d3.chart), which just started providing IE8 support. It seems unlikely that this is causing the problem however, as the code triggering the issue is pure d3.

Comment: What happens if you use an explicit namespace: chart.base.append('svg:g')?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately I still get the same error. The only way I've been able to get around the issue is change all svg g elements to svg:rectangles with fill:none and stroke:none.

Comment: After a little more digging, it seems like the error is only triggered when assigning 'width' and 'height' attributes. other attributes like 'transform', or 'fill' can be applied without error.

Comment: I've got around this for now by assigning width and height to 'g' elements in css instead of with the d3 attr method. Not ideal but it works.

Comment: <g> elements don't have explicit width and height (the bounding box of the g is derived from the children elements). I guess IE treats this as an error instead of just ignoring it.